# A verb for making a new component work for the first time

Tags: single-word-requests

I work with hardware components. When I get a new component I haven't worked with yet, there is a process we do to make it usable. From then on, we know how to use that component and can use it repeatedly. For lack of a better term, we call this process "utilizing the component", but it doesn't really describe it well.

As a metaphor, imagine buying a new TV. Before using it for the first time, you need to assemble its stand, connect it to the power socket, remove the plastic wrap, etc.

Comment: [first] installation

Comment: "Pounded into submission" is the term I usually used.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the phrasal verb to [**set up**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set%20up) which means:

> to assemble the parts of and erect in position
>
> to **put (a machine) in readiness** or adjustment for an operation

Your example:

> I have just set up the new TV so that we can watch it.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: When working with hardware, the term "setup" has a very specific meaning, which would be confusing. Also, I feel it doesn't convey the amount of work put into the process. My metaphor might be lacking, but "setting up" a component like that is more of a serious development process and less "connecting to power outlet".

Comment: @AndyThomas Your example consists of unpacking, assembling, placing it at the right spot, connecting it to power. I don't think there is more suitable verb that can mean all of them at the same time.

Comment: When I worked in electronics we used to use the word install, sometimes set up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **comission**

> Commisioning is the process by which a system, equipment, facility, or plant
>   (which is installed, or is complete or near completion) is installed and tested to
>   verify if it functions according to design objectives, specifications and/or operational requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In IT we would say the part is made **workable** or **production-ready**.

The former usually implies the part now fits into an existing pipeline with minimal changes, while the latter suggests the code was intrinsically improved somehow.

In the lab (biology) where we frequently make tools for experiments, we have a process for cataloging small pieces of equipment that could go together to make something new. This process is called "**tooling**", as in "the part(s) underwent tooling".

Dictionary.com defines tooling as

> the planning and arrangement of tools for a particular manufacturing
>   process

Answer (score 0):

In a broad sense, making a component usable is **initializing** it.

> I initialized the batch of VLSI.

You are also **powering on** a hardware device for the first time.

> We powered on the latest set of widgets.

If there is a self-test that is occurring the power on, then you could borrow a term from computers and say that it is undergoing **POST** (Power-on Self Test) for the first time.

> The processors successfully underwent POST.

And a stray thought from an unrelated area also occurred. When someone in Detroit would hammer a car door into place for the first time (using a rubber mallet), the process was called **finessing** the door.

> The circuit board has been finessed.

(There's a nice irony here of the delicate word "finesse" meeting the subtlety of a mallet.)